# This is not a resource error for png images

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

i am using php magician library for adding watermark on my images when i try to add a watermark.png file on my images it works perfect

```
require_once('php_image_magician.php');
$imagename = '8cbe2235a6428f6e181c13c6b5cd4ade.jpg';
$img = explode(".", $imagename);
$ext = $img[1];
$magicianObj = new imageLib($imagename);
$magicianObj -> addWatermark('watermark.png', 'm', 50, 70);

$magicianObj->displayImage($ext, 100);
```

but when i try to use this code to put watermark file on a png image its giving me error as  **This is not a resource.**

```
require_once('php_image_magician.php');
$imagename = 'abc.png';
$img = explode(".", $imagename);
$ext = $img[1];
$magicianObj = new imageLib($imagename);
$magicianObj -> addWatermark('watermark.png', 'm', 50, 70);

$magicianObj->displayImage($ext, 100);
```

please help me to sort out this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: Post the error you're getting

Comment: **saveImage: This is not a resource ** i am getting this error

Comment: Any luck? I'm also getting this error for jpeg images